# Почему на мобильной версии сайта браузер не полностью масштабируется

Tags: html, css, adaptive

Сделал адаптивный сайт под разрешение 300px. Возникла проблема, что при открытии сайта с мобильного устройства, он как будто бы имеет масштаб 110%, появляется скроллбар вправо. В devtools при прогоне по мобильным устройствам происходит так же. К тому же при уменьшении разрешения тег body начинает занимать меньше места чем есть по факту, даже явное задание width: 100% не исправляет ситуацию. Никакие элементы за тег не вылазят.

[image: пространство, которое появляется при масштабировании]

В мета теге прописано следующее :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Значит какой-то из элементов шире чем экран, не имея [mcve] трудно сказать какой именно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том что я использовал свойство padding у main и header который делал отступы от краев экрана, поэтому верста вела себя неправильно. Удалив соответствующие свойства все пришло в норму